# How To Get Records From Date To Date SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

am going to explain it in pictures and Source Code

**Front Design**

[image]

**Back-end Code**

```
private void AddRecord(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string date = datee.Text + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        if (datee.Text == "" || cusname.SelectedValue == null || Vanda.SelectedValue == null || price.SelectedValue == null || bags.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please fill the data");
        }
        else
        {

            DataRowView dt = (DataRowView)Vanda.SelectedItem;
            string vda = dt["vanda"].ToString();
            DataRowView dt2 = (DataRowView)price.SelectedItem;
            string data2 = dt2["price"].ToString();
            decimal dta = Convert.ToDecimal(data2);
            Int32 pricee = Convert.ToInt32(dta);
            decimal bag = Convert.ToDecimal(bags.Text);
            decimal credit = pricee * bag;
            DataRowView cus = (DataRowView)cusname.SelectedItem;

            string cusidd = cus["id"].ToString();
            int cusid = Convert.ToInt16(cusidd);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("SELECT price - retailprice FROM vanda where vanda = '" + vda + "' and price = '" + pricee + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd5.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            string val = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            decimal valu = Convert.ToDecimal(val);
            Int32 profit = Convert.ToInt32(valu);
            reader.Close();
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insert into records (cusid,datee,description,vanda,price,bag,credit,debit,profit) values ('" + cusid + "','" + date + "','" + des.Text + "','" + vda + "','" + pricee + "','" + bags.Text + "','" + credit + "','','"+profit+"')", con);
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");  
            con.Close();

        }

    }
```

**DataGrid Code**

```
private void enddate_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (startdate.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Starting Date");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(" i need here Query ", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            data.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];
        }

    }
```

**SQL Server Database**

[image]

i hope you will understand it clearly. now clear the bugs and improve my code/logic/query (^_^). bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

Comment: You should switch to explicit `join` syntax. It's standard since 1992!

Comment: i am at beginner level. i have no idea about joining. want records as per my own wished dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your SQL should be using named parameters to avoid SQL Injection Attacks:

```
select r.datee,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.price,r.bag,r.credit,r.debit
from records as r,
     customer as c 
where r.cusid = c.id 
      and c.name = @cname
      and r.datee BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

When you create these variables, which you will pass into your query, format them as follows:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Parse(datee.Text).ToString("M/d/yyyy");
var endDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + " 23:59:59";
```

This will convert the date values to the format your database expects.

Comment: this query select r.datee,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.price,r.bag,r.credit,‌​r.debit from records as r, customer as c where r.cusid = c.id and c.name = @cname and r.datee BETWEEN '"++"' AND '"++"' is not perfect it's only shows that recoreds that have 00:00:00 timings

Comment: I wrote my answer before you included the screenshot of your data. See my update.

Comment: Also, as @mm8 pointed out, dates are not stored as strings in the database. They're a distinct data type; don't confuse the *display* format with the *storage* format: they're distinct. The code above should work just fine, nonetheless.

Comment: i have updated my question now you can understand it clearly.

Comment: Your question was clearer the first time around. There's no way to know what the query should return without being able to see what the grid should contain.

Answer (score 1):

```
select r.datee,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.price,r.bag,r.credit,r.debit 
from records  r
JOIN    customer  c ON  r.cusid = c.id 
WHERE c.name = 'aizaz' AND DateColumn BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't store the dates in any specific string format. A date is a date and it has no specific format. Formatting the output of a date is a UI thing.

You get the actual `DateTime` value of a `DatePicker` using the `SelectedDate` property. You should use pass these values as parameters to your command:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select r.datee,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.price,r.bag,r.credit,r.debit from records as r, customer as c where r.cusid = c.id and c.name = @cname and r.datee BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59));
```

Comment: string start = startdate.Text;
            string end = enddate.Text;
            DataRowView name = (DataRowView)nme.SelectedItem;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select r.datee,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.price,r.bag,r.credit,r.debit from records as r, customer as c where r.cusid = c.id and c.name = '" + name + "' and r.datee BETWEEN '"+start+"' AND '"+end+"'", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            grid.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: That's how you should *not* write a query. By the way, DataRowView is Windows Forms and you have tagged your question WPF. In Windows Forms you get the DateTime value using the Value property of the DateTimePicker class.

Comment: please imrove this code .. and this query select r.datee,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.price,r.bag,r.credit,r.debit from records as r, customer as c where r.cusid = c.id and c.name = @cname and r.datee BETWEEN '"++"' AND '"++"' is not perfect it's only shows that recoreds that have 00:00:00 timings

Comment: wpf application

Comment: Then you should refer to my answer. I updated it to with an example of how to add a time to the end date as well.

Comment: ops i missed DataRowView cus = (DataRowView)cusname.SelectedItem;
                string id = cus["id"].ToString();

Comment: What do you mean? How does that relate to your question about the dates?

Comment: i have updated my question now you can understand it clearly. now i want is improve my source code. mean which is best method to insert date and time that are easy to understand and easy to fetch